# OAuth & OpenID - Need confirmation

Tags: api, rest, oauth, openid

This question has already be asked 20 times and i read a lot about it... but i need confirmation about something. I just want know if i understood good.

The first part is about definitions :

**Identification** : To identify the client, know who it is exactly.

**Authorization** : To allow access to some ressources. No identity here.

**Authentication** : Combine Identification and Authorization.

My first question is : *Reasoning good or not ?*

---

Then, my second part is about OAuth & OpenId :

At the beginning, for the basic implementation, OpenId is only for the Identification part and OAuth is for the Authorization part.

But now, after upgrading, the both tend towards an Authentication part.

For example, OAuth basically can just allow one application to access to another without the password or critical informations of the user through the network. It just do it one time and generate a token which can be revoke or refresh and need to be given for each request.

Now, with the basic implementation of OAuth, if S1 allow S2 to get users informations, i can access to these url : *path_to_s1/api/users/foo* - *path_to_s1/api/users/bar* and i will get the informations (email - contacts... for example) of the user foo when i will be on the first url and of the user bar when i will be on the second url. I just have here the Authorization and not the Identification. For the identification, i can for example implement an API Key or OpenId Connect on the top of OAuth.

My second question is : *Reasoning good or not ?*

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If S1 gives S2 information based on a token, then S1 could have stored information about that token - e.g. the identity of the user. So using oauth for authorization does not mean you cannot have identity information about the user.